# Representing a function in terms of higher order differences

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to write a function in terms of its mollification and higher order
forward differences. Given a function $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and
$h>0$, we set $u_{h}(x):=\frac{1}{h}u\left(  \frac{x}{h}\right)  $,
$x\in\mathbb{R}$. We also define inductively $\Delta_{h}^{1}u(x)=u(x+h)-u(x)$
and $\Delta_{h}^{m}u(x)=\Delta_{h}^{1}(\Delta_{h}^{m-1}u(x))$.

Ilin proved the following result (the proof is in the first volume of O. V. Besov, V. P. Ilin and S. M. Nikolski, “Integral Representation of Functions and Embedding Theorem,”) Let $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a
function of class $C^{m}$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then for every $h>0$ and
$x\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
u(x) &  =\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\left(  x+y\right)  \omega_{h}\left(  y\right)
\,dy\\
&  \quad+\int_{0}^{h}\frac{1}{\xi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_{\xi}(t)\int%
_{\mathbb{R}}\Delta_{\delta z}^{(m)}u(x+t+z)\psi_{\xi}(z)\,dzdtd\xi,
\end{align*}
where $\omega,\phi,\psi\in C_{c}^{\infty}\left(  \mathbb{R}\right)  $, with
support contained in $[0,1]$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\omega(x)\,dx=1$, and
$0<\delta<1$.

The proof is rather long. When $m=1$ there is a much simpler representation
formula, which I think is due to Grisvard.

Let $u\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Then for all $\ell>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
u(x)=\frac{1}{\ell}\int_{0}^{\ell}u(x+t)\,dt-\int_{0}^{\ell}\frac{1}{y^{2}%
}\int_{0}^{y}(u(x+y)-u(x+t))\,dtdy.
$$
The proof goes as follows. By translation it is enough to prove the previous
identity at $x=0$. Let $0<\varepsilon<\ell$. Using integration by parts we
have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\varepsilon}^{\ell}\frac{1}{y^{2}} &  \int_{0}^{y}(u(y)-u(t))\,dtdy=\int%
_{\varepsilon}^{\ell}\frac{u(y)}{y}\,dy-\int_{\varepsilon}^{\ell}\frac
{1}{y^{2}}\int_{0}^{y}u(t)\,dtdy\\
&  =\int_{\varepsilon}^{\ell}\frac{u(y)}{y}\,dy-\int_{\varepsilon}^{\ell}%
\frac{u(y)}{y}\,dy+\left[  \frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y}u(t)\,dt\right]
_{y=\varepsilon}^{y=\ell}\\
&  =\frac{1}{\ell}\int_{0}^{\ell}u(t)\,dt-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int%
_{0}^{\varepsilon}u(t)\,dt\rightarrow\frac{1}{\ell}\int_{0}^{\ell
}u(t)\,dt-u(0)
\end{align*}
as $\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}$ since $u$ is continuous at $0$. On the other
hand, by the fundamental theorem of calculus $u(y)-u(t)=\int_{t}^{y}u^{\prime
}(\tau)\,d\tau$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \frac{1}{y^{2}}\int_{0}^{y}(u(y)-u(t))\,dt\right\vert  &  \leq
\frac{1}{y^{2}}\int_{0}^{y}\int_{t}^{y}|u^{\prime}(\tau)|\,d\tau dt\leq
\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y}|u^{\prime}(\tau)|\,d\tau.\\
&  \leq\Vert u^{\prime}\Vert_{L^{\infty}((0,\ell))}.
\end{align*}
It follows by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem that
$$
\int_{\varepsilon}^{\ell}\frac{1}{y^{2}}\int_{0}^{y}%
(u(y)-u(t))\,dtdy\rightarrow\int_{0}^{\ell}\frac{1}{y^{2}}\int_{0}%
^{y}(u(y)-u(t))\,dtdy,
$$
which concludes the proof.

I am interested in a representation of the type established by Grisvard for
$m\geq2$ and which is simpler than the one proved by Ilin.

Comment: Can you explain (with references?) why you think the formula is due to Grisvard?

Comment: It should be in this paper Grisvard : [1] Commutativité de deux foncteurs d'interpolation et applications (J. Math. pures et appl., t. 45, 1966, p. 143). | Zbl 0187.05803